# Java http requests get banned on site

Tags: java, selenium, web, request, httprequest

I am trying to get information from a site using a Java program I wrote.

When I am using selenium everything is ok, but when I try to use `prowser` or `httpurlconnection` the site blocks my IP.

I am setting user agent to `Chrome/44.0.2403.155`, and other parameters in the original site request (I get them with help of `HTTPFox`).

I am handling cookies (cookies I get from `FirefoxWebDriver`), but the result is always the same: my IP is blocked.

I get the information I need six times, and then site blocks my IP. When I don't use cookies ("logged out mode") everything is ok.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the site's policy, but you're possibly accessing it too many times per minute. Best check the site's policy and follow it.

Comment: I was try to make request 1 time per minute but gets the same result: i get 6 times info that i need and then site blocks my IP. So i think this problem not in time. And one interesting thing: when i don't use cookies in request (logged out mode) everything is ok site give me info 3-4 times per second.